# disable direct child handler of SlidingDrawer and use it via button that not it's direct child

Tags: android

I want to use SlidingDrawer but I need to open it from button which not the child of the SlidingDrawer, can I disable the handler and open the drawer via a button that outside the FrameLayout that wraps the drawer object, or maybe I need to use other object that performs like the SlidingDrawer?
Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an invisible or zero-size handle in the layout and call the SlidingDrawers open(), close(), toggle(), animateOpen(), animateClose() or animateToggle() methods from your button's onClick() listener.